# any field that is a superset of the real numbers is also a vector space over the real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

This seems intuitively true since any such field would have to satisfy being closed over addition/multiplication, etc, which would translate directly to fulfilling vector space axioms. I'm a little confused as to the field only being over the real numbers though. It seems to me that such a field containing the real numbers would either have to be the field of real numbers or the field of complex numbers in order to be closed under addition & multiplication, but I'm not sure how to go about showing that.

Comment: Is the complex numbers not a vector space over the real numbers?

Comment: If $K$ is a field, from a $K$-vector space with basis $\{ e_j\}_{j \in E}$, you need to define a multiplication $e_j e_{j'} = \sum_{i \in E} c_{j,j',i} e_i$ (with $ c_{j,j',i} \in K$) to make it a $K$-algebra ie. a ring containing $K$.  Note $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space but you need things like the axiom of choice to define a basis.

Comment: Well if $\omega$ is in $F$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ then $\alpha = \omega*x^{-1}\in F$ and $\omega = \alpha*x$.  What are the properties of a vector space that we have to verify?  Should be straightforward to verify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got to the wikipedia article on vector spaces and consider the definition.

Okay so we need a set $V$ so that $F \supset \mathbb R$ is such that $F=\{av|a\in \mathbb R; v\in V\}$.

Well... let $V = F\setminus \mathbb R+\{0, 1\}$.

Then

1-3) $V$ is a associative and commutative under addition has an additive identity.  Check, it inherits all those from the field $F$.

4) an additive inverse is in $V$.  Well, an additive inverse is in $F$.  if $v\in \mathbb R$ then $-v \in \mathbb R$ and $-(-v) = v$.  So $v \in \mathbb R \iff -v\in \mathbb R$.  So $v\in V; v\not \in \mathbb R \implies -v\not \in \mathbb R$ so $-v \in V$.  Check.

5-8) scalar (real) multiplication compatibility, multiplicative identity in $\mathbb R$, distributive over scalars (real numbers) over addition of elements of $V$ , distribution of elements of $V$ or addition of reals.  All check.  $F$ is a field.

That's it.

....

Actually, I'm not sure I see any problem with letting $V = F$.  I don't see anything in the definition that requires non-redunancy that some vectors can not also be scalars.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $K$ is a subfield of $L$ then $L$ is a vector space over $K$.

You're right that the reals and the complex numbers are the only finite dimensional field extensions of the reals. This is one formulation of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: i think you mean something like  "the only finite-dimensiional field extensions of the reals".

Comment: @RobArthan, yes, of course. fixed, thanks.